# pivoting for messy data

Tags: r, pivot

I have data that looks like this

```
structure(list(V1 = c("ABT", "AK", "AT", "AZ", "BG", "BT"), V2.1 = c("MLC_7", "MLC_07", "MLC_04", "MLC_07", "0", "0"), V2.2 = c("MLC_8", "0", "MLC_05", "RND_01", "0", "0"), V2.3 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), V2.4 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), V2.5 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

i need work with variable in V2.1:V2.5 so that it becomes

| V1 | MLC_RND | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABT | MLC | 7 |
| ABT | MLC | 8 |
| AK | MLC | 7 |
| AT | MLC | 4 |
| AT | MLC | 5 |

How can i do this? i tried pivot_longer/wider but getting really confused....

Please help!

Comment: `pivot_longer`, `filter`, and `separate` should be sufficient. If you show what you tried, it would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `pivot_longer` to reshape to 'long' format, then `filter` the 'MLC' column where the values are not '0' and `separate` into columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = V2.1:V2.5, values_to = 'MLC') %>% 
  dplyr::filter(MLC != "0") %>%
  separate(MLC, into = c("MLC_RND", "ID"))
```

Comment: If the ID column needs to be numeric, then add `mutate(ID = as.numeric(ID))`

Comment: @BenNorris you can use `convert = TRUE` in `separate`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` option

```
type.convert(
  na.omit(setDT(df)[
    ,
    .(X = unlist(.SD)), V1
  ][
    ,
    c(.(V1), setNames(tstrsplit(X, "_"), c("MLC_RND", "ID")))
  ]),
  as.is = TRUE
)
```

which gives

```
    V1 MLC_RND ID
1: ABT     MLC  7
2: ABT     MLC  8
3:  AK     MLC  7
4:  AT     MLC  4
5:  AT     MLC  5
6:  AZ     MLC  7
7:  AZ     RND  1
```